# Django: Changing User Profile by forms

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-profiles

I am using UserProfile to save some fields that I created. Its working fine. But I would like to create a new view to let user change (update) theses fields values. But, theses values arent being showing in form. Anyone have any idea how to fix it?

**view.py**

```
@login_required

    def atualizar_cadastro_usuario(request):    
        if request.method == 'POST':       
            form = cadastrousuarioForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.get_profile())


            if form.is_valid():            
                new_user = form.save()            
                return render_to_response("registration/cadastro_concluido.html",{})
        else:    
            form = cadastrousuarioForm(request.POST,instance=request.user.get_profile())
        return render_to_response("registration/registration.html", {'form': form})
```

**form.py**

```
class cadastrousuarioForm(UserCreationForm):   
    username = forms.EmailField(label = "Email",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'60','maxlength':'75'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label = "Digite o Email novamente",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'60','maxlength':'75'}))
    nome = forms.CharField(label = 'Nome',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'30','maxlength':'100'}))
    cpf = BRCPFField(label='CPF')
    data_nascimento=forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format = '%d/%m/%Y'), input_formats=('%d/%m/%Y',))    
    endereco = forms.CharField(label = 'Endereço',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'30','maxlength':'100'}))
    cidade = forms.CharField(label = 'Cidade')
    estado = forms.CharField(widget=BRStateSelect(), label='Estado', initial = 'SP') 
    telefone = forms.CharField(label = "Telefone",widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'12','maxlength':'12'}))
    escolaridade = forms.ChoiceField(choices=UserProfile.ESCOLARIDADE_ESCOLHAS)    
    profissao = forms.CharField(label = 'Profissão')
    empresa = forms.CharField(label = 'Empresa',required=False) 
    receber_emails = forms.ChoiceField(choices=UserProfile.QUESTIONARIO_ESCOLHAS)     
    #captcha = CaptchaField(label = 'Digite as letras a seguir')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username","email")


    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(cadastrousuarioForm, self).save(commit=False)  
...
```

In bash, it works fine:

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from cadastro.models import UserProfile
>>> u = User.objects.get(username='user@gmail.com')
>>> u.get_profile().telefone
u'123123455'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your model in the form from `User` to `UserProfile`. The form also needs to subclass `ModelForm` rather than `UserCreationForm`. Also, it looks like you're only using a subset of fields in your ModelForm (`username` and `email`). Finally, since you're using a ModelForm you don't need to define all of the model's fields in your form. Try changing your `cadastrousuarioForm` to the following:

```
class cadastrousuarioForm(ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('username','email')
    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(cadastrousuarioForm, self).save(commit=False)
```

Comment: Rolling Stone, it worked fine! But I would like show just some fields of UserProfile. The solution that your presented, all fields of this model are being showed. Do you have any clue?

Comment: Cool, glad that worked! It's easy to limit the fields, just add the following to your Meta class: `fields = ("username","email")` with all the fields that you'd like to include. I updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Now, it stopped to work :-P 
Unknown field(s) (username, email) specified for UserProfile

Comment: yeah, you have to swap out `username` and `email` with the fields you'd like to use.

Comment: I think that I am completely sleepy. Thanks for your time. It worked great.