# Python Django - Getting Form data for the user profile after logging in (Multiple forms)

Tags: python, django

I am very new to Django as well as Python. I am trying to build a small Resource management tool. Below is what I have come up with till now. 
I Extended a User Model
I have created other required models like Current address Permanent Address etc.
I have a sample form in forms.py 
I have a profile.html page.

As of now when a user is logged , and when he clicks on update profile he is redirected to Profile.html page where he gets fields from ModelForm Employee (Data pulled from DB) which is just a extended userModel. (Infact user should not be able to edit any of the field in this form, this should be just a read only field as this will be set by Admin, but this Problem is later part for me, I do not know how to bring as a ReadOnly field have not researched yet on this)

What I want to do is now I want to show all the other forms also (ModelForms of Current Address, Permanent address etc on the same same page for that particular user so he can update the records) Till now I tried different methods but I couldn't get hold of any proper solution Can anyone help me on this. Below are my models, views, forms and html page. I am open for any alternative solution which is easy and secure as this I have started recently so I am ok to change whatever required to be changed. All the other models are linked to foreign Key emp_id from Employee model. Apologies for the Long question but I am stuck at this point and I unable to go ahead from this point.

Forms:

```
    #User Profile Form to update the user profile
    class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    # If you pass FormHelper constructor a form instance
    # It builds a default layout with all its fields
            self.helper = FormHelper(self)

    # You can dynamically adjust your layout
            helper = FormHelper()
            helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
            helper.layout = Layout(
                Field('text_input', css_class='input-xlarge'),
                Field('textarea', rows="3", css_class='input-xlarge'),
                'radio_buttons',
                Field('checkboxes', style="background: #FAFAFA; padding: 10px;"),
                AppendedText('appended_text', '.00'),
                PrependedText('prepended_text', '<input type="checkbox"         checked="checked" value="" id="" name="">', active=True),
                PrependedText('prepended_text_two', '@'),
        'multicolon_select',
                FormActions(
                    Submit('save_changes', 'Save changes', css_class="btn-primary"),
                    Submit('cancel', 'Cancel'),
                )
            )
            self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save_changes', 'Update'))



        class Meta:
            model = Employee
            exclude = ('user',)
```

Views:

```
   @login_required
   def user_profile(request):
       if request.method == 'POST':
           form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)

           if form.is_valid():
               form.save()
               return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/loggedin/')
       else:
           user = request.user
           profile = user.profile
           form = UserProfileForm(instance=profile)

       args = {}
       args.update(csrf(request))
       args['form'] = form
       return render_to_response('profile.html', args)
```

profile.html:

```
      {% extends "base.html" %}

     {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
     {% block content %}

       <h2> Profile </h2>

       {% crispy form %}

      {% endblock %}
```

Models.

```
#Department Model
class Dept(models.Model):
dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.dept_name
#Extending User Model
class Employee(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name="User Id")
emp_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, max_length=5, verbose_name="Employee Id")
emp_first = models.CharField('First Name',max_length=20)
emp_middle = models.CharField('Middle Name', blank=True, max_length=20)
emp_last = models.CharField('Last Name',max_length=20)
emp_email = models.EmailField('Email Id')
emp_dept = models.ForeignKey(Dept, verbose_name="Department")

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.emp_first

User.profile = property(lambda u: Employee.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])

#Current Address Model
class CurrentContact(models.Model):
emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
emp_add = models.TextField('Current Address')
emp_city = models.CharField('City', max_length=20, default = 'Bangalore')
emp_state = models.CharField('State', max_length=20, default= 'Karnataka')
emp_country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=20, default = 'India')
emp_mobile1 = models.IntegerField('Mobile1',max_length=12)
emp_mobile2 = models.IntegerField('Mobile2', null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
emp_landline = models.IntegerField('Land Line',null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
emp_PerEmail = models.EmailField('Personal Email Id', blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.emp

#Permanent Address Model
class PermanentContact(models.Model):
emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
emp_add = models.TextField('Permanent Address')
emp_city = models.CharField('City', max_length=20, default = 'Bangalore')
emp_state = models.CharField('State', max_length=20,default= 'Karnataka')
emp_country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=20, default = 'India')
emp_mobile1 = models.IntegerField('Mobile1',max_length=12)
emp_mobile2 = models.IntegerField('Mobile2', null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
emp_landline = models.IntegerField('Land Line',null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
emp_PerEmail = models.EmailField('Personal Email Id', blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.emp
#Emergency Contact Model
class Emergency(models.Model):
emp = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
emrg_name = models.CharField('Full Name', max_length=30)
emrg_add = models.TextField('Full Address')
emrg_city = models.CharField('City', max_length=20, default = 'Bangalore')
emrg_state = models.CharField('State', max_length=20,default= 'Karnataka')
emrg_country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=20, default = 'India')
emrg_mobile1 = models.IntegerField('Mobile1', max_length=12)
emrg_mobile2 = models.IntegerField('Mobile2', null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
emrg_landline = models.IntegerField('Land Line',null=True, blank=True,  max_length=12)
emrg_PerEmail = models.EmailField('Email Id', blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.emp
```

Comment: Do you want to show other 'forms' or other 'fields' for editing? A form is something different to a field (which inherits from a form normally). Using a single form, you can enable some fields to be edited and some as read-only.

Comment: @Joe, Thanks for the comment, What I want is to show all the fields related to a particular user i.e. His address, emergency contacts etc: User should be able to edit these fields whenever he wants to update. Hope I am clear. I am ok to implement anyway , but purpose should be solved

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look here:

[Django: Changing User Profile by forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719476/django-changing-user-profile-by-forms)

It seems like an almost identical question to yours.

Comment: I have come across similar solutions where they create User Profile Form containing too many fields, I do not want to have lot of fields under one single User ProfileForm.

Comment: So what you were saying about running multiple forms per User is correct? That part wasn't very clear.

Comment: When I say one single User profileForm i.e. extended userModel in my case Employee Model.  Rest all the models like current address, Permanent address etc are linked to the pk of Employee Model.   (I hope I have created my models properly I mean the relationship is Valid)